# How to get and display all the file icon in android?

Tags: android

My `GridView` display all SD Card files. Each file has their own extensions. My `first.xml` contains one `ImageView` and one `TextView`. My another XML file contains `GridView`.
My sample code is

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Sample/Users/")
String str = file.getName();
```

For example screenshot is
[image]
How to get and display this file icon. I have no idea. If it is possible or not.

Comment: Thats definitely possible, you can have a look at my answer and try out mark accepted if works fine :).

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @Rinkalkumar - Sorry. You are misunderstanding my question.  My Question is `get icon of particular file` not Android Application icon.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this and change accordingly,

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(fileUri);
    intent.setType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("fileExtension"));

    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo match : matches) {
        final Drawable icon = match.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        final CharSequence label = match.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
    }
```